# How to detect GCPW Windows user with C#

Tags: c#, google-workspace

I have a user machine which is logged in to a Google Workspace user domain account using [GCPW](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9250996?hl=en) this works fine the user is logged in and I can see the Device in the workspace admin

[image]

I have a C# console application on the users machine.  I need to detect the users Google workspace domain user.

## what i have tried so far.

**UserName**

```
Console.WriteLine(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
```

returns

```
LINDA-LAPTOP\linda_daimto
```

This does not match anything in workspace console.

**MacAddress**

Mac address does work it does return the mac address of the machine listed in workspace but the issues is then if two different domain users login to the same machine there is no way of knowing which one it is.

**RawResourceId**

I tried [devices.deviceUsers.lookup](https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/reference/rest/v1/devices.deviceUsers/lookup)  rawResourceId but this fine was not created on the machine so it does not exist.  again this probably wouldn't work if two users used the same machine.

## windows registry

I was able to find the users email in the windows registry but I'm wondering if this is a robust solution or just a hack reading from the registry.

> Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Google\Accounts\106744391248434652261

## issue

Does anyone know how to detect the user that was signed in with GCPW